# bibliography style for Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis

Tags: bibliographies

Does anyone know which bibliography style meet the following formatting requirements? The followings are the format required by Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis, I have spend a long searching online but none seems to fit. Could someone help please?

> Brown, S., and J. Warner. "Using Daily Stock Returns: The Case of
>   Event Studies." Journal of Financial Economics, 14 (1985), 1–31.
>
> Ross, S. A. "Return, Risk and Arbitrage." In Risk and Return in
>   Finance, Vol. I, I. Friend and J. L. Bicksler, eds. Cambridge, MA:
>   Ballinger (1977).
>
> Titman, S.; K. C. Wei; and F. Xie. "Capital Investments and Stock
>   Returns." Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis, 39 (2004),
>   677–700.

Comment: I checked the journal's website -- it does indeed feature different punctuation before the last author of two-author works (comma) and of three-or-more-author works (semicolon).

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no predefined bibliography style for Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis. You have two options creating your own bibliography style:

1. Using the tool [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) (makebst).

   > This is the custom-bib package for generating customized BibTeX
   >   bibliography styles from a generic file by means of the docstrip
   >   program that is part of the LaTeX2e installation.
2. Using the package [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and modify a predefined style on the LaTeX-level.

As often I recommend the second option because it's more flexible. (In my opinion it's easier, too)

Answer (score 0):

For JFQA you will likely have to make your own bst file, see this [link](http://gabrielelanaro.github.io/blog/2014/12/01/latex-bibliography-in-5-minutes.html):

As you will notice, when you run `latex makebst` you will have to answer many questions. See my choices (only those where I differ from the default) below. Feel free to add suggestions.

Before showing you my bst choices, please note that you will probably have to put this into your tex document: `\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}`

Here are my bst choices, from the dbj file that the process creates:

```
%% Driver file to produce my_jfqa.bst from merlin.mbs
%% Generated with makebst, version 4.1 (2003/09/08)
%% Produced on 2016/04/07 at 8:28
%% 
\input docstrip
\preamble
----------------------------------------
*** JFQA style ***
\endpreamble
\postamble
End of customized bst file
\endpostamble
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\def\MBopts{\from{merlin.mbs}{%
%<<STYLE OF CITATIONS:
  ay,%: Author-year with some non-standard interface
%<<AUTHOR--YEAR SUPPORT SYSTEM (if author-year citations)
  nat,%: Natbib for use with natbib v5.3 or later
%<<AUTHOR NAMES:
  nm-rev1,%: Only first name reversed, initials (AGU style: Smith, J. F., H. K. Jones)
%<<EDITOR NAMES IN COLLECTIONS (if author names reversed)
    %: (def) Editor names NOT reversed as edited by J. J. Smith
%<<POSITION OF JUNIOR (if author names reversed)
  jnrlst,%: Junior comes last as Smith, John, Jr.
%<<JUNIOR PART IN THE CITATION (if author-year citations)
    %: (def) No `junior' part in the citations but in the ref listing
%<<PUNCTUATION BETWEEN AUTHOR NAMES:
  aunm-semi,%: Names separated by semi-colon 
%<<LABEL WHEN AUTHORS MISSING (if author-year citations)
  keyxyr,%: Year blank when KEY replaces missing author (for natbib 7.0)
%<<DATE FORMAT (if author-year citations)
  yr-par,%: Year in parentheses as (1993)
%<<TRUNCATE YEAR (if author-year citations)
  note-yr,%: Year text full as 1990--1993 or `in press'
%<<TITLE OF ARTICLE:
  tit-qq,%: Title and punctuation in double quotes (``Title,'' ..)
%<<COLLECTION/PROCEEDINGS TITLES (if quoted title)
  bt-qq,%: Quote collection and proceedings titles too
%<<CAPITALIZATION OF ARTICLE TITLE:
  atit-u,%: Title style (just as in bib entry)
%<<JOURNAL VOL AND NUMBER:
  vnum-x,%: Journal vol, without number as 34
%<<VOLUME PUNCTUATION:
  volp-com,%: Volume with comma as vol(num), ppp
%<<YEAR IN JOURNAL SPECIFICATION:
  jdt-pc,%: Year, comma, pages as 34(2), (1995), 1345--1387
%<<NUMBER AND SERIES FOR COLLECTIONS:
  num-xser,%: Allows number without series and suppresses word "number"
%<<PAGES IN BOOKS:
  bkpg-x,%: Pages in book bare as 50-55
%<<PUBLISHER ADDRESS:
    %: (def) Publisher, address as Harcourt, New York
 add-pub,%: Address: Publisher as New York: Harcourt
%<<ISBN NUMBER:
  isbn,%: Include ISBN for books, booklets, etc.
%<<ISSN NUMBER:
  issn,%: Include ISSN for periodicals
%<<EDITOR IN COLLECTIONS:
  edby,edbyy,%: In booktitle, .., editor 
%<<ABBREVIATE WORD `PAGES' (if not using external language file)
  ppx,%: `Page' omitted 
%<<ABBREVIATE WORD `EDITORS':
  ed,%: `Editor' abbreviated as ed. or eds.
%<<EDITION NUMBERS:
  xedn,%: Editions as in database saving much processing memory
%<<COMPATIBILITY WITH PLAIN TEX:
  nfss,%: Use LaTeX commands which may not work with Plain TeX
  }}
\generate{\file{my_jfqa.bst}{\MBopts}}
\endbatchfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution file starting from Martien's response, but applying adequate changes. You can find it below (from my dropbox).

[This is my solution file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yclwfb2dshr5m5p/AADPh1C1QCsJrM-DmXkr4qcZa?dl=0)

Comment: Please try to avoid external links and include your solution [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192)