# Creating and using custom referencing style

Tags: bibliographies

first of all, I'm a tex virgin so my knowledge of the tools and terminology is pretty much at the same level with a fish.

I'm using Win7(64 bit). I installed winEdt.

I want to write a paper with a custom referencing style that my school demands. It is very similar to harvard style with some differences (3 authors for et al. kind of stuff). My questions are

1. How can I modify the existing style or create a new style by changing the copy of an existing one?
2. How do I add reference details to my project. Is there a program like Endnote where you can store all your references, modify them and use directly to create refs in Word?
3. How do I add references in my text?
4. Does latex auto update my bibliography when I add a new reference in text?
5. How do I add sources in the bibliography by hand? I want to add sources that I don't cite but used.

please explain like you are explaining to an idiot.

a lot of questions but I really want to go on with and learn LaTeX, but unless I can find answers to these, I will go on with the Ms Word solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: You mention that your school requires the use of a custom "harvard" (author-year, right?) style for referencing and citing pieces. Do you know if a bibliography style file (extension `.bst`) exists that implements this style. Creating a new `.bst` file from scratch isn't too difficult if you use the `makebst` utility, but it's better if you can save yourself this step, right? Separately, since you're brand-new to LaTeX, be sure to work through an introductory-level tutorial such as the [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) by Tobi Oetiker.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80174/bibliography-style-for-journal-of-financial-and-quantitative-analysis/101608#101608

Comment: Incidentally, you didn't mention *which* TeX distribution you use. Either [TeXLive](http://tug.org/texlive/) or [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/) should work very well Windows7 and your editor (WinEdt, right?).

Comment: @Mico there is no predefined .bst file for that custom style. However, as I said, the style is close to harvard (author-year).

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I am using MiKTeX

Comment: There is no *single* "harvard" style. :-( The `harvard` package comes with the following .bst files: agsm, apsr, dcu, jmr, jphysicsB, kluwer, and nederlands. Do you know (a) which one of these styles is reasonably close to your custom style and (b) what the output should actually look like (if different from what's produced by the existing style file)? By the way, *many* packages besides the `harvard` package also implement authoryear-style citations. One of them is the `natbib` package, which has some advantages over the older `harvard` package (such as better support for `hyperref`).

Comment: @Mico After reading the documentation, the default harvard style seemed to be more or less enough since my school recommends using harvard (but my instructor said there are some differences between original harvard and theirs). I will try to use each one of the .bst files and see which one suits me.

Comment: You could also look into the `biblatex` package, which allows for extensive fine-tuning (and you could get all the help you need here). See this question for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102662/harvard-reference-using-biblatex